# Dynamically build a SQL Insert statement based on results from a DataView

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a legacy data logging industrial app that I'm writing a new interface for.  The program lets you select points on devices, save those to a profile, then select devices to apply that profile for.   When you apply the profile it create a table for each device using the devices unique ID as the table name and creates columns for each point of data you will be logging using the unique point ID.  For example I select 3 points of information to datalog and it saves those three as a Profile (into it's own table) and then the point into the Points table tagged with that Profile:

```
PointID      PointName     ProfileID
33            Temp23        1
34            Hum14         1
35            Stat          1
```

I then select a couple devices and apply that profile which saves to the Device table:

```
DeviceID     DeviceName     ProfileID
5            NWUnit         1
6            NEUnit         1
```

After it saves the devices it creates the table per device such as:

```
Table Name:  DEV5
Column 1:  PNT1 - Float
Column 2:  PNT2 - Float
Column 3:  PNT3 - Bit
```

As you can see the table names are directly related to the device ID and the column names directly related to the point ID.  I can add/remove points form the profile, it adds/deletes columns as needed.  Apply a different profile and the DEV tables get deleted and recreated.  Everything works as expected like the old program that's being replaced.

Now I need to actually do the data logging.  I created a simple view:

```
SELECT     dbo.Devices.DeviceID, dbo.Points.PointName, dbo.Points.PointID
FROM       dbo.Devices LEFT OUTER JOIN
                dbo.Points ON dbo.Devices.ProfileID = dbo.Points.ProfileID
```

Again so far so good:

```
DeviceID     PointName     PointID
5            Temp23         33
5            Hum14          34
5            Stat           35 
6            Temp23         33
6            Hum14          34
6            Stat           35
```

I take this and I throw it in a DataTable, do a Columns.Add("Value") to it to get a blank column, then go through a data retrieval.  When it's done I now have the table with the retrieved value:

```
DeviceID     PointName     PointID     Value
5            Temp23         33          72.34
5            Hum14          34          43.8
5            Stat           35          1
6            Temp23         33          76.80
6            Hum14          34          54.2
6            Stat           35          0
```

And that's where I'm stuck.  I need to take this info, use the DeviceID for the table name and the PointID for the column name, and insert the data.  In otherwords I need this:

```
Dim myParamList As New Dictionary(Of String, Object) From {
                        {"@SampleTime", Date.Now},
                        {"@DevTable", "Dev" & r.Item("DeviceID")},
                        HOW DO I CYCLE THROUGH TO GET THE COLUMNS HERE?
                    }
                    UpdateDatabase(MySQLConnection, "INSERT INTO @DevTable (SampleTime, AND HERE?) VALUES (@SampleTime, AND HERE)", myParamList)
```

I cannot figure out the cycling through part.  I thought I should use a Count + Group By to find out how many rows have the same device ID, like DeviceID 5 has 3 rows, and use that to cycle through that number of times but I'm just stuck trying to figure out how.

Any suggestions on the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after struggling with trying to do a GroupBy on a dataview I decided to just do another database query with a Count(*) and GroupBy DeviceID to grab my unique DeviceIDs:

```
DeviceID     RowCount
5             3
6             3
```

I then used that to loop through the device ID's and used the ID to filter myView as needed.  Then I dynamically created a parameterized SQL string and update the database:

```
For Each r As DataRow In DevIDDataset.Tables("DeviceIDs").Rows
    myView.RowFilter = "DeviceID=" & r.Item("DeviceID")
    Dim myParamList As New Dictionary(Of String, Object) From {
        {"@SampleTime", Date.Now}
    }
    Dim myFields As String = "SampleTime"
    Dim myValues As String = "@SampleTime"
    For Each row As DataRowView In myView
        Dim myPointID As String = row.Item("PointID")
        myFields += ",obj" & myPointID
        myParamList.Add("@obj" & myPointID, row.Item("RetrievedValue"))
        myValues += ",@obj" & myPointID
    Next
    UpdateDatabase(MySQLConnection, "INSERT INTO dev" & r.Item("DeviceID") & " (" & myFields & ") VALUES (" & myValues & ")", myParamList)
Next
```

Not pretty but it does what it needs to do and I can't think of any other way to do it.